# fc not found when executing a shell script

Tags: shell, ubuntu, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the following shell script zsh_history_fix.sh:

```
# Fixes a corrupt .zsh_history file
mv ~/.zsh_history ~/.zsh_history_bad
strings ~/.zsh_history_bad > ~/.zsh_history
fc -R ~/.zsh_history
rm ~/.zsh_history_bad
```

Anytime I try to execute `./zsh_history_fix.sh`, it throws `./zsh_history_fix.sh: 4: fc: not found`.
Any idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: Did you check for invisible funny characters in your file? With, say, `od -bc ./zsh_history_fix.sh`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FYI:
fc seems like a build in command for zsh only.
I guess you dont add *#!/bin/zsh* in the top of the file,
so the shell will executed in bash environment by default.
Thus terminal gives you the error fc: not found.

### to solve

add *#!/bin/zsh* in the first line

Comment: `fc` is a POSIX shell feature (under the UP = User Portability option), so it is available in many shells of Bournian descent.